# is Microsoft IIS Media Services still maintained?

Tags: windows, iis, web-server

any articles i find about IIS Media Services seems to be from 2012 and not much for updates since then. Is that because it's been working well since then? or because it's no longer being maintained? I'd like to use it for some basic stuff since i am running windows servers anyway, but was wondering if it's safe and actively maintained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, IIS Media Services is a dead end product. The installer is no longer available, and only supports releases of IIS that are end of life or will soon be end of life.

Also refer to the following:

https://halfblood.pro/status-of-iis-out-of-band-modules-80a3af57c489

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65818542/how-do-you-add-media-services-to-the-iis-10-manager

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/media-services/#overview

Comment: hey greg, thanks for stopping by. your answer reflects what the lack of information from microsoft seems to suggest. you wouldn't happen to have any thoughts on what windows users could run as an on-prem media server, would you? azure media services are rather expensive, especially for someone who has a nice server array running anyway.

Comment: If you are really inclined, I would ditch Windows. Microsoft is still interested in desktop products, but interesting stuff like this disappeared long ago.

Answer (score 0):

The old official [link](https://www.iis.net/media) to IIS Media Services forward to [Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/media-services/).

But I can't find official MS page to say it is deprecated. Seems like it is replaced by service.